# package inputenc error unicode char - (U+2212) error

Tags: symbols, unicode

I'm getting this error package inputenc error unicode char - (U+2212) on the following part of my text: (it's happening at lines 98-99)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{Discrete math Assignment 4}
\author{Me}
\date{January 2018}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\textbf{Exercise 4b)} Let $x \in N$. Let $x_k, x_{k−1}, \cdots , x_1, x_0$  %98       
be the digits of $x$, so that %99
$$x = x_k 10^k + n_{k-1} 10^{k-1} + \cdots + x_1 10 + x_0.$$
Note that $10 \equiv -1$ ($\mod{11}$). Thus
$$x \equiv x_k(-1)^k + x_{k-1}(-1)^{k-1} + \cdots -x_1 + x_0  (mod\ 11 )$$

$$ = (x_0 + x_2 + x_4 + \cdots ) - (x_1 + x_3 + x_5 + \cdots) ( mod\ 11).$$

We have $11|x$ if and only if $x \equiv 0 ( mod\ 11)$, i.e. if and only if
$$x_0 + x_2 + x_4 + \cdots \equiv x_1 + x_3 + x_5 + \cdots\  (mod\ 11). $$
In other words, $11|x$ if and only $11$ divides the difference of the sums
of the even and odd place digits of $x$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}` before `\begin{document}`